# Get equidistant intervals on approximated bark scale

Tags: algorithm, matlab, math, octave, numerical

Wikipedia says we can approximate Bark scale with the equation:

`b(f) = 13*atan(0.00076*f)+3.5*atan(power(f/7500,2))`

How can I divide frequency spectrum into `n` intervals of the same length on Bark scale (interval division points will be equidistant on Bark scale)?

The best way would be to analytically inverse function (express `x` by function of `y`). I was trying doing it on paper but failed. WolframAlpha search bar couldn't do it also. I tried Octave `finverse` function, but I got error.

Octave says (for simpler example):

```
octave:2> x = sym('x');
octave:3> finverse(2*x)
error: `finverse' undefined near line 3 column 1
```

This is `finverse` description from Matlab: http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/finverse.html

There could be also numerical way to do it. I can imagine that you just start from dividing the `y` axis equally and search for ideal division by binary search. But maybe there are some existing tools that do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to numerically solve this equation (there is no analytical inverse function). Set values for `b` equally spaced and solve the equation to find the various `f`. Bissection is somewhat slow but a very good alternative is Brent's method. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brent%27s_method

Answer (score 1):

This function can't be inverted analytically. You'll have to use some numerical procedure. Binary search would be fine, but there are more efficient ways to do these sorts of things: look into [root-finding algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm). You can apply your algorithm of choice to the equation `b(f) = f_n` for each of the frequency interval endpoints `f_n`.

Answer (score 1):

I finally decided not to use the Bark values approximation but ideal values for critical bands centres (defined for `n=1..24`). I plotted them with `gnuplot` and on the same graph I plotted arbitrarily chosen values for points of greater density (for the required `n>24`). I adjusted the points values in `Hz` till the the both curves were approximately the same.

Of course **rpsmi** and **David Zaslavsky** answers are more general and scalable.

Answer (score 1):

Just so you know, in (say) octave to implement rpsmi's or David Zaslavsky's answer, you'd do something like this:

```
global x0 = 0.

function res = b(f)
   global x0
   res = 13*atan(0.00076*f)+3.5*atan(power(f/7500,2)) - x0
end

function [intervals, barks] = barkintervals(left, right, n)
    global x0
    intervals = linspace(left, right, n);
    barks     = intervals;
    for i = 1:n
        x0 = intervals(i);
         # 125*x0 is just a crude guess starting point given the values
        [barks(i), fval, info] = fsolve('b', 125*x0);
    endfor
end
```

and run it like so:

```
octave:1> barks
octave:2> [i,bx] = barkintervals(0, 10, 10)
[... lots of output from fsolve deleted...]
i =

 Columns 1 through 8:

    0.00000    1.11111    2.22222    3.33333    4.44444    5.55556    6.66667    7.77778

 Columns 9 and 10:

    8.88889   10.00000

bx =

 Columns 1 through 6:

   0.0000e+00   1.1266e+02   2.2681e+02   3.4418e+02   4.6668e+02   5.9653e+02

 Columns 7 through 10:

   7.3639e+02   8.8960e+02   1.0605e+03   1.2549e+03
```